Refresh Salesforce OAuth Refresh Token Before Expiry with Named and External Credentials
I'm currently facing an issue with Salesforce OAuth refresh tokens and would appreciate some guidance.
Problem:
I have a setup in Salesforce where I use Named Credentials and External Credentials to authenticate against an external third-party service that uses AWS Cognito user pools. The refresh token provided by Cognito is configured to expire after 30 days. The refresh token is used to generate new access tokens, and this process works fine for the entire duration of 30 days. However, once the refresh token expires, my protected resource calls result in 'Token Expired' errors.
Requirement:
Is there a way to refresh the refresh token before its expiry time, similar to how we rotate the access token? Specifically, I want to understand how to:
Use the current access token or refresh token to refresh the refresh token within its expiry period using Salesforce's OAuth flow with Named and External Credentials.
Ensure that the refresh token is refreshed regularly to prevent expiration issues.
Additionally, I'd like to understand how platforms like Gmail manage tokens to last for long durations (e.g., months or years) without frequent manual re-authentication.
Context:
The refresh token has a 30-day expiry period.
Once expired, protected resource calls fail with 'Token Expired' errors when calling external third-party services using AWS Cognito user pools.
Attempts:
I have configured the Named Credentials and External Credentials in Salesforce.
The refresh token still expires after 30 days, causing 'Token Expired' errors.
Questions:
Is there a built-in mechanism in Salesforce to refresh the refresh token within its expiry period using OAuth flow?
How can I ensure seamless long-term authentication similar to platforms like Gmail?
Thank you for your help!

In OAuth, the refresh token is the mechanism by which access tokens are refreshed. If the refresh token itself expires, a user must log in again. There is no mechanism in OAuth to "refresh" a refresh token without having a username and password (i.e. logging in again). The only way to prevent this from happening is to change the refresh token to have a longer expiry time.

Thanks @sfdcfox We relaised that and we also tried from AWS , but it not happened, finally we changed the expiry time of refresh token to our requirement.
